# How do I assign numeric values to text in one cell in Excel or Numbers and add them

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to track the time a person spends doing multiple tasks in different days (production time) and for each task I need to assign a value - duration.

[image: Picture attached with the forma]

I have tried the formula in B8

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(B2:B4,{"Task 1","Task 2","Task 3"})*{0.5,0.2,0.2})
```

but the problem is that if I have multiple tasks in one cell it would not return a value.

*On a different spreadsheet I have created a drop down menu from where I can allocate multiple tasks to one person and they will be displayed on this  spreadsheet in one cell*

Comment: What version of Excel?  Also Windows or MAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this solution I will use Excel 4.0 macros.

I created a Named Range called *ProductionTime* with this formula:

```
=EVALUATE("SUM("& SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(GET.CELL(5,OFFSET(INDIRECT("RC",FALSE),-6,0)), "Task 1", 0.5), "Task 2", 0.2), "Task 3", 0.2) &")")
```

Use it in `B8` in order to sum the text in `B2`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is really useful. At the moment I am trying to get my head around the get.cell function as I have never used it before. When I am trying to use the same formula on another cell it becomes invalid. Could you please give me some guidance in understanding the syntax so I can apply it on for different cells?

Comment: This part of the syntax: GET.CELL(5,OFFSET(INDIRECT("RC",FALSE),-6,0). I know that 5 is used for contents of reference the only part I don't understand is why -6 and 0

Comment: 0 is the offset for *columns*. Your are interested in the same column, so no offsetting for columns. However, you need to go up 6 rows. That translates to -6 for rows.